# SDL_RenderPresent doesn't work

Tags: c++, render, sdl-2

i see only screenshot. But when i don't use thread, render works normal and i see my textures.

```
void CApp::ShowRender() {
 while (mRunning) {
    SDL_RenderPresent(mRender);
}
```

}

Comment: You should contextualize your problem better.

Answer (score 2):

SDL_render.h
These functions must be called from the main thread.
See this bug for details: http://bugzilla.libsdl.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1995

Answer (score 0):

You didn't call SDL_RenderClear.

A texture isn't just an image that could stay on your screen, it's an image that is constantly replaced by annother image.

Calling renderpresent presents the image and that's all, it can't present another image unless you clear your renderer. It's like putting trash inside a full trashcan.

> > LOOP
> >
> > {
> >
> > SDL_RenderClear(mRender)
> >
> > TEXTURES
> >
> > ShowRender()
> >
> > }

This should work